# Why isn't this iframe sizing to 100%?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Given the following page that includes an iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/public/stylesheets/main.css">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="min-height: 100; margin: 0px">
        <iframe src="testpage.html" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">
    </body>
</html>
```

When it is launched, the iframe would only seems to load part of the text from `testpage.html`. How would one make the iframe show the entire content of `testpage.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `html` and `body` height to 100% too.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

You may (or may not) also need to set `display` on `iframe` to block:

```
iframe { display:block; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting min-height in body to 100% do the trick? i had mine set to 100 and forgot the % sign. i did add it to see if it wouold do the trick, but no show